# Rails build_association with child class in has_one best practice advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a User class defined like this

```
class User
end
```

And I have sublassed this to create an Owner class and created a has_one relationship with another Company class

```
class Owner < User
  has_one :company
end

class Company
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

In my Users controller when creating a new User I want to accomplish the following:

1. Create a new User
2. Create a new Company
3. Associate the User with the Company (as the Owner i.e. company.owner_id)

I can accomplish this with the following code (simplified for brevity)

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])

  if @user.save
    @company.owner_id = @user.id
    @company.save
    ...
```

Now, this just feels ugly to me, but I can't seem to get the whole build_asociation process to work as expected (yes, fields are there in both dev and test).

What should I be doing here?

Comment: Is your `@owner` saved successfully?

Comment: no.. It was a validation issue. I was in the console due to somehting not working in the controller that I was trying to understand - I'm going to update the question and details to reflect the main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create `Owner` and `Company` at the same time, I suggest you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in `Owner`. Here's the code:

```
class Owner < User
  has_one :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end
```

Then in your controller you can do something like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user]) # should it be User or Owner?
  @user.company_attributes = params[:company] # assume two separate forms for User and Company
  # if you use fields_for, however, company attributes are nested under params[:user] automatically.

  if @user.save
    # do your job here
  end
end
```

For complete reference, please take a look at [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) and the view helper [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)